# jQuery TimePicker theme is not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

What I have missed? My timepicker looks like this, it doesn't use the theme for timepicker.

[image]

Inside html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
<link type="text/css" href="css/jquery.ui.all.css" />
<style type="text/css">
    #ui-datepicker-div, .ui-datepicker{ font-size: 80%; }
    .ui-timepicker-div .ui-widget-header { margin-bottom: 8px; }
    .ui-timepicker-div dl { text-align: left; }
    .ui-timepicker-div dl dt { height: 25px; margin-bottom: -25px; }
    .ui-timepicker-div dl dd { margin: 0 10px 10px 65px; }
    .ui-timepicker-div td { font-size: 90%; }
    .ui-tpicker-grid-label { background: none; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }
</style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-1.7.1.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.min.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.js" ></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js" ></script>


<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#time").timepicker({
            addSliderAccess: true,
            sliderAccessArgs: { touchonly: false }
        }); 
    });
</script>
</head>

<body>
    <input type="text" value="" id="time" />
</body>
</html>
```

Do I have wrong order of loading for js files?

[image]

Some reference link.

[jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/eb8Dz](http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/eb8Dz)

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does the theme that you downloaded have a theme name?  Sometimes the theme CSS path might need to include that name... for example, if the theme name is "**custom-theme**", it would be like this:

```
<link type="text/css" href="css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
```

Unless you are sure that the paths are correct for your CSS files.  It just seems like the CSS part isn't actually getting found, from your first screenshot.

**EDIT:**

After looking at the links below, it looks like there's a problem with the jquery-ui theme CSS file (that particular *Overcast* theme CSS file.)  It seems to work if I change out that top CSS link to something like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/css/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css" />
```

Also note: that CSS link seemed to need the extra:

```
rel="stylesheet"
```

in there... otherwise it still wouldn't appear correctly.

The *ui-lightness* theme might not be what you are looking for... but, I would probably try re-downloading the *Overcast* theme to see if that works.

Comment: The links are correct. Please try this sample I made, the still exist here: http://jsfiddle.net/MyNameIsCode/eb8Dz/16/

Comment: Thanks for the links; please read the rest of my answer above :)

Comment: +1 Wow you got it, it doesn't work in jffiddle.net but it works on my project. Thanks a lot!!! :)